# Client restful jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, rest-client

My idea was to create one function that returns the value of the call at rest service.

Code from inside function:

```
.....

var dddd;
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://localhost:8084/GetSomeRest/asdf/ddd/arbol/1",  
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     async: "false", // with this line add solved
     success: function (dataaa) {
         // do something
       dddd= dataaa.name;
         alert(dddd);// here has value
     }}); 
alertt(dddd); //here is null
.....
```

What is the problem? Any help is welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dddd;

 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://localhost:8084/GetSomeRest/asdf/ddd/arbol/1",  
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (dataaa) {
         // do something
       dddd= dataaa.name;
         alert(dddd);// here has value
     }}); 
alert(dddd); --> this is fired before assigning value through ajax
```

Ajax call is not completed when you call that alert outside ajax call